# How can I disable a particular cell of a row in extjs 4.1.1 when edit using row editor?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

How can I disable a particular cell of a row when edit in extjs 4.1.1? i am using gridrow editor. I have a grid which has 2 columns, name and age. When click for edit I have to disable the name field, the user can only edit age.

Comment: Please help me as soon as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can only edit using the row editor, then don't  specify the editor config on the column. 
If you can add too, then you could try the following ( I haven't ever done it myself, but it should work) :

```
grid.on('beforeedit', function(editor, e, eOpts) {
     // if editing.. 
     this.down('column[dataIndex=name]').setEditor(null);
     // else
     this.down('column[dataIndex=name]').setEditor(/* editor config */);
}, grid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
grid.on('beforeedit', function(editor, e, eOpts) {
         // if editing.. 
         if(e.field == "name"){
               e.cancel = true;  
          }
    });
```

Setting e.cancel as **true**  will disable the field from editing.